# Как сохранить записи из терминала в файл

Tags: python, sql

Имеется код для Python который подключается к базе данных и select вытаскивает необходимые мне данные. Вот код

```
import cx_Oracle

conn_str = u'login/password@ip/user'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(u"SELECT subs_subs_id, number_history, navi_user FROM subs_histories WHERE subs_subs_id IN (SELECT subs_subs_id FROM subs_histories where end_date < start_date GROUP BY subs_subs_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) and start_date > '01.12.2021' and end_date < '02.12.2021' ORDER BY subs_subs_id, start_date, end_date")
for row in c:
    print (row[0], "-", row[1], "-", row[2], "-", row[3], "-", row[4])
conn.close()
with open('text_out.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write(row[0], row[1], row[2])
f.close()
```

НЕ получается сохранить полученные данные в txt файл, в чём моя проблема?

Comment: Открытие файла назначения должно быть до цикла перебора записей, запись в файл - внутри цикла. А `print` можно вообще убрать за ненадобностью.

Comment: @Akina на счёт ```print``` согласен. А вот если открытые записи в файл загнать в цикл, то он записывает одну последнюю строчку. Вроде сейчас наткнулся на костыль который исправит, и теперь запись сохраняется, но только последний результат цикла, а не весь))) Но это мать его костыль

Comment: *если открытые записи в файл загнать в цикл, то он записывает одну последнюю строчку.* Ой, да ладно сказки-то рассказывать! или ты там что-то ну очень не так делаешь... ты часом close в цикл не притащил? должно быть `c.execute; f.open; for row: fwrite; f.close`.

Comment: @Akina ```close``` не совал, есть привычка не совать что попало, куда попало. Хотя по моему коду в ответах такое не скажете ^_^

Comment: " есть привычка не совать что попало, куда попало" - хаха, а зачем тогда в код в вопросе сунут f.close()? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import cx_Oracle

conn_str = u'rep_server/UZreporting@10.0.202.67:1521/bisprim'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(u"SELECT subs_subs_id, number_history, navi_user FROM subs_histories WHERE subs_subs_id IN (SELECT subs_subs_id FROM subs_histories where end_date < start_date GROUP BY subs_subs_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) and start_date > '01.12.2021' and end_date < '02.12.2021' ORDER BY subs_subs_id, start_date, end_date")

with open('text_out.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    for row in c:
        print(row[0], "-", row[1], "-", row[2], file=f)
conn.close()
```

Comment: не сработало) вернулся к тому с чего начал))

Comment: @МухаммадёрЖураев "не сработало" - неинформативно. Если ошибка - показывайте полный текст сообщения, если поведение отличается от желаемого - описывайте подробно, чем именно.

Comment: спасибо вам обоим, данный код сработал. Просто я один и тот же код дважды вставил и не вчитывался. Мой косяк, вопрос закрыт)))